# Enable Rust nightly feature when project feature is enabled

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In a library crate I want to make backtraces available on demand and use the Rust nightly backtrace feature. In order to do that, Rust requires setting `#![feature(backtrace)]` in my crate root.

Is there a way to express *I want Rust nightly feature "backtrace" only when my create level feature "backtraces" is set*?

Non compiling pseudo code to help illustrating what I have in mind:

```
#[cfg(feature = "backtraces")]
#![feature(backtrace)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute):

```rust
#![cfg_attr(feature = "backtraces", feature(backtrace))]
```

If the first argument is true then the subsequent attribute(s) will be applied.